# Why does Listbox.Drawitem get called many times?

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I have a databound listbox on my C# WinForm that holds strings that are links to image file locations.  I want to display the image as a thumbnail for the user to click on and view.  I got it working correctly by setting DrawMode=OwnerDrawVariable and handling the DrawItem and MeasureItem events.

However I noticed that I have to click exit 2 times to get out of the application (looks like it's called selectedIndexChanged on first click, then exits on second).  On further inspection I noticed that the DrawItem event is fired a multitude of times when I click an item in the listbox (like 15+ times).  There is only 1-2 items EVER in the listbox at a time!  Why is it getting called soo many times?

I tested this with a non databound simple listbox and it does the same thing.  I am only curious as I have to read the image from disk and get a thumbnail of it to put into the listbox, which if it did that 15-20 times could affect performance (and is TOTALLY unnecessary).

```
private void listBox1_MeasureItem(object sender, MeasureItemEventArgs e)
{
   MessageBox.Show("listBox1_MeasureItem");
   // Cast the sender object back to ListBox type.
   ListBox theListBox = (ListBox)sender;

   // Get the file path contained in each item.
   DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)theListBox.Items[e.Index];
   string fileString = drv.Row["fullpath"].ToString();

   // Create an image object and load image file into it
   Image img = Image.FromFile(fileString);
   e.ItemHeight = Convert.ToInt32(img.Height * 0.15);
   e.ItemWidth = Convert.ToInt32(img.Width * 0.15);
}

private void listBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
   MessageBox.Show("listBox1_DrawItem");
   // If the item is the selected item, then draw the rectangle
   // filled in blue. The item is selected when a bitwise And  
   // of the State property and the DrawItemState.Selected 
   // property is true.
   if ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected)
   {
      e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.CornflowerBlue, e.Bounds);
   }
   else
   {
      // Otherwise, draw the rectangle filled in beige.
      e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Beige, e.Bounds);
   }

   DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)listBox1.Items[e.Index];
   Image img = Image.FromFile(drv.Row["fullpath"].ToString());
   img = img.GetThumbnailImage(e.Bounds.Width, e.Bounds.Height, null, IntPtr.Zero);
   e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y);

   // Draw the focus rectangle around the selected item.
   e.DrawFocusRectangle();
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't use `MessageBoxes` in painting/drawing events — it interferes with the painting/drawing event.

Comment: I would also cache those images so that you aren't doing an `Image.FromFile(...)` from within a drawing / measuring event.  That really would slow down your performance.

Comment: Once again, despite its flaws, I'm reminded of the awesomeness of WPF.

Comment: Oh God no, as Lars says, you really shouldn't place blocking calls like that in an OnPaint type method.

Comment: Doh, that makes sense now but never really occurred to me.  I'll use debug statements instead.  By caching the images do you mean storing them in-memory in an array or list?  Because there are 100,000+ of them and all are < 200k.  I guess i'd have to load them from FS as I figure out which one(s) user is requesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure and this would have to be tested, but [this article makes me believe that what I am going to say is true.](http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/8014/1954)

Basically, if you go by the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.drawitem.aspx):

> Occurs when a visual aspect of an owner-drawn ListBox changes.

So, this means that everytime an item is added, this event is called. Also, I think even when you perform certain drawing actions within this method, it will call itself (you might be able to avoid this using [SuspendLayout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.suspendlayout.aspx) and [ResumeLayout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y53zat12.aspx) on the listbox while updating), but am not sure.

Here is the kicker as far as I know it. Everytime this event is triggered, it is pretty much for every item in the list. (This might be useful in that you can de-color a previously selected item, so dont jump directly to what I am about to suggest without thinking it through). So, the DrawItemEventArgs has an index of the item being drawn. Using that, you can focus in on a specific item that you need to draw. That might help you from re-processing something that has already been processed (keep in mind the notes from the above article..copied below, about index being allowed to be -1).

To visualize this process:

```
Add 1 item  ->DrawItem

Add 2nd item->DrawItem
            ->DrawItem

Add 3rd item->DrawItem
            ->DrawItem
            ->DrawItem

Add nth item->DrawItem * n
```

So, this actually results in a kind of [fibonacci type situation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) (3 items resulted in 6 calls...5 would result in your 15 number), and you can see how the initial load could be cumbersome, and how adding a new item make for n calls to the method.

From the article above:

> **The ListBox calls the DrawItem method repeatedly, for each item in its
>   Items collection.**
>
> The DrawItemEventArgs argument to the DrawItem event handler exposes
>   an Index property whose value is the index of the item to be drawn.
>   Watch out! The system raises the DrawItem event with an index value of
>   -1 when the Items collection is empty. When that happens you should call the DrawItemEventArgs.DrawBackground() and DrawFocusRectangle()
>   methods and then exit. The purpose of raising the event is to let the
>   control draw a focus rectangle so that users can tell it has the
>   focus, even when there are no items present. The code traps for that
>   condition, calls the two methods, and then exits the handler
>   immediately

Answer (score 1):

If a dialog box pops up over the top your control, guess what your control has to do when you close the dialog box? It has to redraw itself!

Try using Debug.Writeline to write debugging information when you are looking at drawing controls. Of course, you still need to be careful that you don't pull up Visual Studio over the top of your form as well! It's a situation where two monitors can really help.